# how to create new rails generator for dropping a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, generator, drop-table

I creating an app that needs to be able to create and drop tables on the fly, on create it's pretty simple I use:

 `rails g model User name:string`

but there is no generator for dropping a table.

I want to make it be possible to: 

`rails g migration DropTableUser`

Answer (score 0):

To correct your question, `rails g migration User name:string` would result in a migration called User not a model, I guess what you meant was `rails g model User name:string`.

To answer your question, I think it would result in an unnecessary mental effort, especially since something like this already exists in:

`rails [d|destroy] model User`

If you want to still implement yours, I'd advise that you look at Rails Generators instead for a way to help you out. I guess that would be dependent on creating a migration template etc.

Comment: this will destroy the model but not the db table.